# Storing static data in JSON file vs PHP file itself?

Tags: php, json, web-services, web, static-data

I'm writing a web service in PHP using the slim framework. Any request made to any endpoint will only be allowed if (a) the request is coming from a list of IPs (b) the HTTP request header contains a secret string, which is static (I know this isn't the best way to secure a web service, but this service is mostly for internal use and we don't need anything more complicated).

Should I store the list of IPs and the shared secret in a JSON file or should I initialize the array of IPs and the shared secret string in the PHP script itself?
Storing it in a JSON file would mean that the data would have to be read from disk on every HTTP request. I'm assuming this is bad as far as performance is concerned?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a file of const with all IPs: https://secure.php.net/manual/it/function.define.php and than used it with `require`